# Updating Values after Closure

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying fetch data from firebase and storing it in a dataModel using completion handler like this

```
static var dataModels = [DataModel]()

static func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("data")
    ref.observe(
        .value,
        with: { snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]] else {
                return
            }

            for data in value {
                guard let contentArray = data["content"] as? [[String: String]] else {
                    return
                }

                var content = [Content]()

                for item in contentArray {
                    guard let imageURL = item["imageURL"],
                        let title = item["title"],
                        let description = item["description"]
                    else {
                        continue
                    }

                    content.append(
                        Content(imageURL: imageURL, title: title, description: description))
                }

                guard let videoURL = data["videoURL"] as? String,
                    let videoTitle = data["videoTitle"] as? String,
                    let videoDescription = data["videoDescription"] as? String
                else {
                    continue
                }

                let dataModel = DataModel(
                    videoURL: videoURL, videoTitle: videoTitle, videoDescription: videoDescription,
                    content: content)

                DataFetch.dataModels.append(dataModel)
            }

            // Reload your table view after the data has been fetched and appended

            completion()
        })
}
```

and accessing it like

```
DataFetch.fetchData {
    self.title.text = DataFetch.dataModels[0].videoTitle
}
```

but i want to set the number of rows for

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 0

}
```

I tried by using

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numberOfRows: Int?
    DataFetch.fetchData {
        number = DataFetch.dataModels[0].content[0].count
    }
    return numberOfRows!
    // Return Found Nil error
}
```

When I tried to debug it's coming inside of fetchData but it's showing nil in return.

Any Solution for this

Comment: You need to display something (an empty table, at least) while data is being loaded and then update the table when new data is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code to

```
var numberOfRows: Int? 
override func viewDidLoad() {  
   super.viewDidLoad()
   DataFetch.fetchData { [weak self] in
       self?.numberOfRows = DataFetch.dataModels.first?.content.first?.count
       self?.tableView.reloadData() 
   }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return numberOfRows ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfRowsInSection` is supposed to be

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataModels.count
}
```

nothing else. And the data source array `dataModels` is supposed to be an **instance** property in the same class where the table view is located.

```
var dataModels = [DataModel]()
```

After receiving the data pass the `dataModels` array in the closure and assign it to the data source array. Then call `reloadData()` on the table view instance to refresh the table. Please note that an empty array is passed in case of an error

```
static func fetchData(completion: @escaping ([DataModel]) -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("data")
    ref.observe(
        .value,
        with: { snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]] else {
                completion([])
                return
            }

            var dataModels = [DataModel]()
            for data in value {
                guard let contentArray = data["content"] as? [[String: String]] else {
                    completion([])
                    return
                }

                var content = [Content]()

                for item in contentArray {
                    guard let imageURL = item["imageURL"],
                        let title = item["title"],
                        let description = item["description"]
                    else {
                        continue
                    }

                    content.append(
                        Content(imageURL: imageURL, title: title, description: description))
                }

                guard let videoURL = data["videoURL"] as? String,
                    let videoTitle = data["videoTitle"] as? String,
                    let videoDescription = data["videoDescription"] as? String
                else {
                    continue
                }

                let dataModel = DataModel(
                    videoURL: videoURL, videoTitle: videoTitle, videoDescription: videoDescription,
                    content: content)

                dataModels.append(dataModel)
            }

            // Reload your table view after the data has been fetched and appended

            completion(dataModels)
        })
}
```

and call it

```
DataFetch.fetchData { [weak self] items in
   self?.dataModels = items
   self?.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```